# Asp Net Core FileContentResult Audio File to Safari

Tags: javascript, audio, asp.net-core, safari, web-audio-api

In Safari (11), a static audio file loaded into a src via html or javascript works, albeit with the limitations of requiring user input before playing.

ex.

```
<audio src="static.mp3">
```

or

```
var audio = new Audio('static.mp3');
audio.play();
```

work fine.
However, I need to load audio files from the database, so I was using a controller action like so:

```
public FileContentResult GetAudio(int audioId)
    {
        if (!DbContext.Audios.Any(a => a.Id == audioId))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var audio = DbContext.Audios.Single(a => a.Id == audioId);
        return File(audio.File, "audio/mp3");
    }
```

and set like

```
<audio src="getaudio?audioId=1">
```

or

```
var audio = new Audio('getaudio?audioId=1');
```

it will not play in MacOS (Safari) or iOS, but works fine in Chrome and Edge (except on iOS). Depending on how I configure things, I get some form of `Unhandled Promise` error. I've also tried loading into a `Web Audio` buffer, with the same exact success and failures.

Does anyone have a solution or workaround to load my audio files on Safari?

**EDIT**

Ok, so on further testing, I discovered that it's not so much whether the files were sent via action or static file, it's how they were *saved* to the database in the first place. I'm now working to figure out why files I save (as `byte[]`) and then reload are not recognized by Safari.

Comment: If you check the server logs does it report a successful response?

Comment: Always successful from the server. No errors. I've got an update I'll post here in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it turns out, I was *making* the recordings with `MediaRecorder`, which is a fairly new feature in Chrome and a few other browsers. It didn't matter what format I told it to save as, because only `webm` is supported. And guess who doesn't support `webm` format? Safari. Any other browser was picking it up fine, regardless of what incorrect extension I put on the file.

When I find a `webm` to `m4a` conversion, I will add it here. I'm sure there are some solutions out there.